# Empty list of products using firebase extension for stripe payment

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments, firebase-extensions

I am having the following problem.
I am using the firebase extension for stripe payment in a node.js + react app (both v18):
https://extensions.dev/extensions/stripe/firestore-stripe-payments

I am trying to get the products but have an empty list in return.

Simplified version of my code :

```
import { getProducts, getStripePayments } from "@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments";

     const payments = getStripePayments(app, {
        productsCollection: "products",
        customersCollection: "customers"
    })

     async function displayProducts(){
        console.log("Loading products");

        const products = await getProducts(payments);

        products.forEach((p) => console.log(p));

        console.log("Product loaded");
    }
```

My *payments* variable works just fine to create a checkout session.

I have the product in Stripe and in Firebase Firestore :

### Firestore

[image: Firestore]

### Stripe

[image: Stripe]

Any ideas why I can't get the products in the project ?
Don't hesitate to ask for more details.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Closing VSCode and restarting the server seemed to have solved the issue